# wordpress how to refresh reader's screen when a post is edited

Tags: php, wordpress, push, page-refresh

There is one guy reading a post while someone is editing it.
When the editor saves the post and publish it, how to refresh the reader's screen?

Now I do it with an automatic refresh every 10sec (low frequency to avoid splash screen).

Thanks for you help.

Thierry

Comment: Automatic refresh every 10 seconds? And if I'm in the middle of reading something when that happens? Does it just refresh and I suddenly lose my place on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Mari M – this is probably not such as good idea and in general, I'm not even sure it's worth the hassle? Will the user really lose a lot if he misses some content?

One way of doing this without interrupting the reader *too much* is using AJAX – I'm sure you'll find lot of guides of how to use it. Say you write some JavaScript to query the server everything 10 seconds – the backend will then check if the content has update, say, via the "update_date" or a similar field in the database, if it has, it will return the update text.

The issue now is how to properly insert the text without refreshing everything – that's up to you to figure out.

**An alternative** solution would be to simply display a popup of some sort saying that *This article has been changed, you may want to refresh it* and provide a link/button to do so.